# The Azure OS disk size specified for the virtual machine is too large?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vhd, azure-virtual-machine

I have VHD file (actually downloaded from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/BIVHD/enus/). I want ot run it as VM (IaaS) on Azure.
The file is 60 GB when I upload it to Azure with this command:

csupload Add-Disk -Destination "http://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/SQLImage2012Disk.vhd" -Label SQLImage2012Disk.vhd -LiteralPath "E:\SQL Image 2012\SQL Image 2012\Virtual Hard Disks\SQLImage2012.vhd" -OS Windows

I see that it is uploaded, but the size is 250 GB!!!?

Why the size has expand so much?
Because the size is 250 GB I receive this error message when try to provision virtual machine from it:

The OS disk size specified for the virtual machine xxx is too large. 
The maximum supported OS disk size is 128 GB, but the VHD specified has a size of 250 GB.

The questions are:
Why the size change from 60 GB to 250 GB ?
What can i do to manage to provision VM from this disk in Azure ?

thanks in advance

Comment: From your description it seems this is a dynamic VHD that was set at a maximum size of 250 GB, with 60 GB used. If you have access to Hyper-V, please use the [Inspect](http://www.hyper-v-mart.com/HowTo/Check_HyperV_Hard_Disk_Size.aspx) command to check the disk size and add a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from the comment is the answer:
"From your description it seems this is a dynamic VHD that was set at a maximum size of 250 GB, with 60 GB used. "